# Django completely broken even after reinstalling it

Tags: django

Let me preface this by saying that my knowledge on django and web development in general is very superficial.

I was messing around with security configs on my django project, trying to make my website use https (which since then I learned is not that easy to do) but I got it into a redirect loop I believe (the website never loads). I tried to revert all my changes but couldn't get to run the website locally. After looking for answers on google in vain I decided to start the project from scratch (I had just started it anyway). But now even that doesn't work, even the [Writing your first app tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/intro/tutorial01/) doesn't work.

After that I reinstalled python and all the dependencies expecting that to clear every possible thing that I had changed but it didn't, still the same problem, websites never load trying to use https.

Where else could the problem in my system be?

Comment: Your question is a bit too vague for anyone to give a helpful answer. What platform are you hosting your application on? Are you using a CDN? What does your settings.py look like?

Comment: The problem is when running locally. I didn't modify settings.py in the tutorial example or how it comes by default when you create a project. It is exactly as it was when it was working.

Comment: so what error are you currently getting when you run ‘python manage.py runserver’?

Comment: If I don't try to go to the website no errors, when I enter it logs an error saying "You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP."

Comment: did you try removing the ‘s’ in ‘https://‘ in the URL Address bar?

Comment: yes, it still tries to use https

Comment: If you have tried all of that, including reinstalling the app, it might be a caching issue. Try deleting your cache/cookies and restarting your computer. If that doesnt work, it is definitely a setting you are overlooking (such as SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT being set to True)

Comment: That was it, the cache/cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted cache and cookies and it solved the problem.